# Getting screen size and use in drawbit map

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

This is not my activity! this is separate class file
i am using Surface view extended to my class file . i wanted to display a small bit map to my canvas my bit map is very small than my phone screen so i used a `createscaledbitmap` to fit it in my phone screen with this code here

```
  Bitmap  o2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( hud, 800, 490, false);
```

it worked great in my phone but when i tested in a bigger phone  i have my bitmap pasted only 3/4 of the screen .. so i want to make my bitmap to fix the phone screen size

```
Bitmap  o2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( hud, phonescreenwidth, phonescreenheight, false);
```

is there a function to get the phone display size and use in my code ?
like
      `int phonescreenwidth = surfaceView.getwidth ();`

and there is a function called  `protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)`
i dont know how to use it . if someone know please tell me how too :)

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

BY this way you can get width and height of your device and pass it in your method..

```
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int width, height;
    LayoutParams params;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        height = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    } else {
        Point point = new Point();
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        width = point.x;
        height = point.y;
    }
```

Comment: this is not my activity .. this is a separate class file  thats used to draw bitmaps

Comment: In that class if you have a context object then replace getApplicationContext with your context object..otherwise send context object from your activity to that class

Comment: For determinig the screen dimensions we must and should context then only we can get..

Comment: Bitmap o2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(hud,getWidth() , getHeight(), false);

Comment: Bitmap o2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(hud,getWidth() , getHeight(), false); is not working why ?

Comment: have you implemented this two methods and set the value getWidth() , getHeight()??

Comment: print those values to check whether the screen width is coming or not??

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;`

Refer here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

and

[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

try this to get Screen size,,

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

then try passing context from ur baseActivity to the current activity

and then try context.getWindowManger....

Comment: getWindowManager() is undefined for my class